# Why is my JS function always returning true?

Tags: javascript

```
function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById('name').value = "") {
        alert('Name field is required!');
        document.getElementById('name').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('email').value = "") {
        alert("Email field is required!");
        document.getElementById('email').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('password1').value != document.getElementById('password2').value) {
        alert("Passwords have to match!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

HTML :

```
<form id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="success.html">
```

Why is it always returning true, even if one of these fields are empty?

Comment: As for why using assignment (`=`) instead of `==` or `===` causes that to happen above: `if (x = "")` assigns `""` to `x` and then tests the assigned value. Since `""` is falsy, the condition is false.